# Perl cgi sql нужна помощь

Tags: sql, perl

Структура БД:

```
$dbh->do("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS catalog");
$dbh->do("CREATE TABLE catalog (".
         "    id       int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,".
         "    surname  varchar(50)      NOT NULL DEFAULT '',".
         "    name     varchar(50)      NOT NULL DEFAULT '',".
         "    comment  varchar(1250)     NOT NULL DEFAULT '',".
         "    height   varchar(5)       NOT NULL DEFAULT '',".
         "    bust     varchar(5)       NOT NULL DEFAULT '',".
         "    talia    varchar(5)       NOT NULL DEFAULT '',".
         "    bedra    varchar(5)       NOT NULL DEFAULT '',".
         "    shoes    varchar(5)       NOT NULL DEFAULT '',".
         "    hair     varchar(50)      NOT NULL DEFAULT '',".
         "    lang     varchar(250)     NOT NULL DEFAULT '',".
         "    educ     varchar(250)     NOT NULL DEFAULT '',".
         "    m_code   varchar(50)      NOT NULL DEFAULT '',".
         "    hidden   int(1) unsigned  NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,".
         "    PRIMARY KEY (id)".
         ");"
);

$dbh->do("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS catalog_links");
$dbh->do("CREATE TABLE catalog_links (".
         "    pid   int(1)  unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,".
         "    cid   int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,".
         "    sort  int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,".
         "    PRIMARY KEY (pid,cid)".
         ");"
);

$dbh->do("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS images");
$dbh->do("CREATE TABLE images (".
         "    id    int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,".
         "    pid   int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,".
         "    ptype varchar(10)      NOT NULL DEFAULT '',".
         "    ext   varchar(10)      NOT NULL DEFAULT '',".
         "    name  varchar(50)      NOT NULL DEFAULT '',".
         "    main  int(1) unsigned  NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,".
         "    sort  int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,".
         "    PRIMARY KEY (id)".
         ");"
);
```

Запрос сам к БД:

```
my $hash = {};
    if ($pid) {
        my @items = ();
        my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT c.*, i.id as im_id, i.ext FROM catalog c, catalog_links cl, images i WHERE c.hidden=0 AND c.id=cl.cid AND (i.pid=c.id AND i.ptype=? AND i.main=1) AND cl.pid=? ORDER BY cl.sort DESC");
        my $rvs = $sth->execute('catalog', $pid) or die "execute: ".$sth->errstr."\n";
        while (my $item = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
            $item->{lang} =~ s/,/<br>/g;
            push(@items, $item);
        }
```

Спасибо большое за ответ. Но у меня все равно не хватает понимая, как это сделать дальше.
Как я понимаю, в моем коде из БД брались строки, которые относились к одной модели. Далее взятые строки превращались в @items или  $item. Потом вот этим кодом делалась разбивка (сколько этих моделей (или @items) на странице, сколько в одной строке):

```
if (@items) {

                  my $count = @items;
                my $count_from = ($curpage-1)*$items_on_top;
            my $count_to = $count_from+$items_on_top;
            $count_to = $count if ($count<$count_to);
            my @items = @items[$count_from .. ($count_to-1)];
            if (@items) {
                my (@it_top, @it_bot) = ();
                my $cnt = 0;
                for (my $i=0; $i<$items_on_top; $i++){
                    if ($i<$items_per_line) {
                        if ($items[$i]) {
                            push(@it_top, $items[$i]);
                            $cnt++;
                        } else {
                            push(@it_top, {sp=>1}) if @it_top;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if ($items[$i]) {
                            push(@it_bot, $items[$i]);
                        } else {
                            push(@it_bot, {sp=>1}) if @it_bot;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (@it_top) {
                    $it_top[0]->{first} = 1;
                    $it_top[-1]->{last} = 1;
                    $hash->{it_top} = \@it_top;
                }
                if (@it_bot) {
                    $it_bot[0]->{first} = 1;
                    $it_bot[-1]->{last} = 1;
                    $hash->{it_bot} = \@it_bot;
                }
                $hash->{"cols".$cnt} = 1;
            }
            if ($count>$items_on_top) {
                my $pages = (int($count/$items_on_top))+(($count%$items_on_top)>0?1:0);
                $hash->{nav} = &navigation($curpage, $pages);
            }   
        }
```

Как мне превратить Ваш код в такой же массив? Чтобы далее не было проблем с выводом уже в браузер. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Уберите простыню шаблона, он к вопросу пока никакого отношения не имеет. И приведите структуру таблиц с пояснениями, касающимися запроса, где там что.

P.S. Собственно, ни к перлу, ни к CGI вопрос вообще не имеет отношения. Вам нужно переписать всего один запрос, вот его в текущем виде + структуру таблиц и достаточно показать.

Comment: Спасибо. Обновил вопрос, добавил структуру БД и пояснения, как работает БД.

Answer (score 2):

У вас сейчас получается такая структура в `@images`:

```
( 
  [ данные модели 1, фото модели 1 ],
  [ данные модели 2, фото модели 2 ],
  ...
)
```

Вам нужно изменить структуру. Как-то так (я специально использую готовые куски вашего sql, чтобы сильно не запутывать):

```
# сначала строим список моделей:
my $models = $dbh->selectall_hashref
(
  "SELECT c.*, cl.sort FROM catalog c, catalog_links cl
  WHERE c.hidden=0 AND c.id=cl.cid AND cl.pid=$pid",
  'id'
);

# теперь для каждой модели читаем её картинки
foreach my $mid ( keys %$models )
{
  $models->{$mid}->{images} = $dbh->selectall_hashref
  ( 
    "SELECT id, ext, main, sort FROM images WHERE pid=$mid AND ptype='catalog'",
    'id'
  );
}
```

После чего в `$models` получаем такой хэш (он же ассоциативный массив), где ключи - ID моделей, значения - набор данных по каждой из них:

```
1 =>
{
  'sort' => 111,
  'surname' => 'Foo',
  'name' => 'Bar',
  'comment => 'Baz',
  # ...
  'images' =>
  {
    1 => 
    {
      'main' => 1,
      'sort' => 20,
      'ext' => 'foo'
    }
    2 => 
    {
      'main' => 0,
      'sort' => 10,
      'ext' => 'bar'
    }
    # ...   
  }
},
2 =>
{
  'sort' => 222,
  'surname' => '...',
  'name' => '...',
 # ...
},
# и т.д.
```

---

Я исходил из того, что начальный код крив до безобразия. Одно только чтение **всех** моделей из таблицы и формирование среза по странице **вручную** чего стоит. Поэтому предложил для начала воспользоваться более адекватными структурами данных, потом уже разбираться с остальным. Но если так не хочется делать нормально, то можно и криво:

```
my $items = $db->selectall_arrayref
(
   "SELECT c.* FROM catalog c, catalog_links cl
   WHERE
   c.hidden=0 AND c.id=cl.cid AND cl.pid=$pid 
   ORDER BY cl.sort DESC",
   { Columns => {} } 
);

$_->{images} = $db->selectall_hashref
(
    "SELECT * FROM images WHERE pid=$_->{id} AND ptype='catalog'", 'id'
),
$_->{lang} =~ s/,/<br>/g
  for @$items;
```

Соответственно, меняется только то, что вместо массива `@items` будет использоваться ссылка на него (`$items`). Надеюсь, уж как работать со ссылкой вы знаете.  Но учтите, что **точно такого же** массива в любом случае не будет, *по условиям задачи*. И разбираться с кодом вам всё-таки придётся. Так может стоит ковыряться в более прямом коде, чем продираться через кривой и избыточный? Но тут уже хозяин - барин :)

---

Но если вы в принципе не хотите писать код даже на самую-самую капельку лучше, то:

```
my @items;
my $sth = $dbh->prepare
(
    "SELECT c.* FROM catalog c, catalog_links cl
    WHERE
    c.hidden=0 AND c.id=cl.cid AND cl.pid=? 
    ORDER BY cl.sort DESC" 
);
$sth->execute($pid) or die "execute: ".$sth->errstr."\n";

while (my $item = $sth->fetchrow_hashref)
{
    push(@items, $item);
}

$_->{images} = $dbh->selectall_hashref
(
    "SELECT * FROM images WHERE pid=$_->{id} AND ptype='catalog'", 'id'
),
$_->{lang} =~ s/,/<br>/g
  for @items;
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ! Помогите мне еще чуть-чуть. Я обновил сообщение главное. Спасибо.

Comment: См. обновление.

Comment: Спасибо. Но сервер утверждает, что
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: called with 1 bind variables when 0 are needed 
в строке
$sth->execute($pid) or die "execute: ".$sth->errstr."\n";

Вы пишите такой прозрачный и понятный код, а у меня все равно ничего не получается :( Почему я попросил сделать код под старый вариант пагинации - я думал, что так быстрее будет, чтобы не обременять Вас своими проблемами.

Comment: Ну естественно, у меня там опечатка, не `AND cl.pid=$pid`, а `AND cl.pid=?`.

Упс, ещё опечатка в самом конце: `AND ptype='p'` => `AND ptype='catalog'`

Comment: ЗАРАБОТАЛО! Но, не до конца. Информация из catalog выводится исправно. А вот получить данные с images я как-то не могу. Раньше выводилось так <img src="^[$::webpath]/big_^[$im_id].jpg">. Но теперь ведь нет $im_id. Я пробовал просто $id - но просто $id это ссылка на номер модели, а не номер фотографии модели. После каких-то манипуляций я получил это: HASH(0x802227b28) - это хранится в $images - насколько я понял. Я понимаю, что вроде как запрос берет данные из таблицы images - а как мне расшифровать то, что он берет? Нужно "разыменовывать"?

Comment: Это ваш шаблонизатор, и только вам знать как он работает и как туда подставлять данные. Картинки лежат в `item->images` в виде хэша, где ключи - `images.id`:

    images => 
    {
      1 =>  
      {
        id     => 1, # не ошибка, id и ключ, и в значениях
        main   => B1,
        sort   => C1,
        # ...
      },
      2 =>  
      {
        id     => 2,
        main   => B2,
        sort   => C2,
        # ...
      },
      # ...
    }

То есть:

    use Data::Dumper;
    foreach my $image ( keys %{$item->{images}} )
    {
        print Dumper( $image );
    }

Comment: Бьюсь - бьюсь...
^[@it_top ... @] - таким образом я получаю доступ к тому, что хранится в КОНКРЕТНОМ @items. Внутри этой конструкции с помощью вот таких ^[$height] я очень просто вывожу данные. Я не могу разобраться, как мне вывести ссылку на картинку. Т.е. там ведь точно такой же текст, который подставляется в url картинки. Что мне нужно прописать внутри ^[@it_top @], чтобы получить доступ к images? Я пробовал ^[@it_top ^[@images ^[$id] @] @]. И еще кучу разных вариантов этой записи. Но я явно что-то упускаю. Либо подставляется $id, которое взято из catalog (а не из images), либо ничего.